# Is C compiler allowed to optimize away access to unallocated memory?

Tags: c

Consider the below code.

```
int main()
{
  int* p = (int*)0xABCDEFAB;
  int a;

  a = *p;

  /* do something with a */

  return 0;
}
```

Is the compiler allowed to optimize away access to memory location pointed by `p`? As it is not allocated (so its content is undefined) and memory access is not an observable behavior of the program it should be allowed, but on the other hand p may point to a memory-mapped I/O.

What is the formal answer from the C standard point of view?

NOTE: The compiler for sure should not optimize away the access if p was defined as volatile int*, but it is not volatile.

Comment: The C standard imposes no requirements on the behaviour of your program. At all.

Comment: compiler does not know that this memory is not allocated, it could be memory used for some device to communicate (for example direct access to video buffer), so compiler is not allowed to optimize it

Comment: @Lashane Does it not matter that p is not volatile? If your statement is correct, how to justify it based on the standard?

Comment: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/kps2015/proceedings/KPS_2015_submission_29.pdf

Comment: The program is ill-formed. You need an explicit conversion to convert between an integer and a pointer. The only thing the compiler is not allowed to do is to accept it silently.

Comment: @n.m. Corrected - added explicit cast.

Comment: Now the answer by Margaret is 100% correct.

Answer (score 3):

From a [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified *[when the integer evaluates to 0]*, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

Basically, the C standard doesn't deal with manually crafted addresses, only with addresses taken from objects.

---

If, for your implementation, `0xabcdef` turned out to be unaligned, referencing it would be undefined behavior<sup>1</sup> (and the compiler can omits the load).

If `0xabcdef` is aligned, the pointer `p` may not point to the address `0xabcdef` or to an object of type `int`, referencing it would be implementation specific<sup>2</sup>.
The compiler cannot directly omit the load in this case but as the overall behavior is implementation specific, the final result maybe trivial and optimizable away.

For example suppose we have a compiler where integers starting with *ab* are all 
mapped to the architectural address `0xffff` and that for the target architecture, such address reads always 0 (in any system).
The compiler may optimize the load away and zero out `a` directly.

In order to prevent this latter case you need to use `volatile`.

---

In short, your case is not fully covered by the standard.
However there is a note reading

> The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
>   be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.

Meaning that while the standard gives you no warranties, you can expect a compiler to behave reasonably.
Also, by the standard, the integer-pointer mapping should be documented.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Quoting:
If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is
undefined.

<sup>2</sup>
Quoting from the *Annex J, implementation specific behavior*, a list of implementation specific aspects:
- The result of converting a pointer to an integer or vice versa.
- The number, order, and encoding of bytes in any object

Comment: Thanks for covering the conversion problem, byt the main focus of the question was if the compiler may omit the load, no matter what the address is held by the pointer. As I understand your answer is NO, even if p is not volatile, correct?

Comment: @mrn ...mmm, I would rather say YES. Due to the conversion integer-pointer you may have undefined or implementation specific behavior. In the former case, the answer is YES. In the latter the answer is YES, if you don't use `volatile`, NO otherwise.